# How to fix the error when using Roboteq controller driver with ROS2 humble?

Tags: controller, driver, ros2

I have Roboteq controller to control brushless DC motor and want to use it with ROS2 humble. So for the ROS2 driver I was using this fork https://github.com/DoanNguyenTrong/roboteq_controller_ros/tree/galactic-devel to build it with ROS2 humble but got error in ./controller_driver/src/roboteq_controller_ros/roboteq_controller/include/roboteq_controller/roboteq_controller_node.h in line 26 #include "nav_msgs/msg/odometry.hpp". So can not find the header for the nav_msgs. But when just comment the line it works. So my question is do we need the header or how to fix it if need it?

Thanks